# Struggling to have 3 formulas in the same line

Tags: math-mode, labels, line

Wondering if anyone can help with the below.

Basically I would need the 3 formulas with the correspondent reference in the same line.  For Precision formula I would need the (2)  like the (1) is in Recall formula,  and same for F1 formula.  Struggling to get the 3 formulas in same line and the below  is the best I could get,  but still not right.

See below the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  \begin{equation}
  Recall = \frac{TP}{TP +FN}
    \label{eqn:1}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
  Precision = \frac{TP}{TP + FP}
    \label{eqn:2}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
  F1 = 2 * \frac{ Precision * Recall}{Precision + Recall}
    \label{eqn:3}
  \end{equation}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Is is a requirement that they all have separate equation numbers? Because otherwise this can be one with a onliner `align` (which then gives one number to the entire collection). That seems a lot simpler than using a tabular.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Comment: yeah, it is a requirement that each formula has a different equation number ...  but I am struggling to get that right.  See below what I got from the code above:

Comment: sorry, I can't find the way to attach an image of the output of my code ...

Comment: you can use the image upload but before posting delete the `!` from the generated markdown (you will not need that last step once you get more points here) (I'll do it this time)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be specific saying how to make something fit as you gave no indication of your fonts (which affects the size of the expression) or the page size.

Here are a couple of possibilities using the default fonts and default US letter paper with article class.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,amsmath}

\begin{document}

Small

{\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
p{.29\textwidth}
p{.31\textwidth}
p{.4\textwidth}
@{}}
  \begin{equation}
  \mathrm{Recall} = \frac{\mathrm{TP}}{\mathrm{TP} {+}\mathrm{FN}}
    \label{eqn:r}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
  \mathrm{Precision} = \frac{\mathrm{TP}}{\mathrm{TP} {+} \mathrm{FP}}
    \label{eqn:p}
  \end{equation} &
  \begin{equation}
  \mathrm{F1} = 2 * \frac{ \mathrm{Precision} {*} \mathrm{Recall}}{\mathrm{Precision} {+} \mathrm{Recall}}
    \label{eqn:f}
  \end{equation}
\end{tabular*}

}

Multline

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
p{.25\textwidth}
p{.27\textwidth}
p{.4\textwidth}
@{}}
  \begin{multline}
  \mathrm{Recall} =\\ \frac{\mathrm{TP}}{\mathrm{TP} +\mathrm{FN}}
    \label{eqn:rr}
  \end{multline} &
  \begin{multline}
  \mathrm{Precision} =\\ \frac{\mathrm{TP}}{\mathrm{TP} + \mathrm{FP}}
    \label{eqn:pp}
  \end{multline} &
  \begin{multline}
  \mathrm{F1} =\\ 2 * \frac{ \mathrm{Precision} * \mathrm{Recall}}{\mathrm{Precision} + \mathrm{Recall}}
    \label{eqn:ff}
  \end{multline}
\end{tabular*}


\end{document}
```

Note you should avoid using the default math italic for multi-letter words (it is designed to look like a product of one-letter variables) and it's best to avoid numeric `\label`

I avoided `tabularx` <strike>because I wrote it</strike> because by default it makes the columns equal width and here you want to adjust the columns "by eye" to fit in the expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much David!!  That really worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can't fit those three equations in a standard line, unless you reduce their size.

Here's a fairly general way to use all the available space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\manualequation}[3][]{%
  % #1 = optional size command, #2 = label, #3 = equation
  \mbox{%
   #1%
   $\displaystyle{#3}$\enspace\refstepcounter{equation}\ltx@label{#2}\thetag{\ref{#2}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2][1-5]
\begin{equation*}
\hspace{0pt}
\manualequation[\small]{eqn:1}{
  \mathrm{Recall} = \frac{\mathit{TP}}{\mathit{TP} + \mathit{FN}}
}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\manualequation[\small]{eqn:2}{
  \mathrm{Precision} = \frac{\mathit{TP}}{\mathit{TP} + \mathit{FP}}
}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\manualequation[\small]{eqn:3}{
  F_1 = 2 \frac{\mathrm{Precision}\cdot\mathrm{Recall}}{\mathrm{Precision} + \mathrm{Recall}}
}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[3][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The trick is to add some glue at the left side, then insert very large glue in the middle, but shrinkable to make the chunks to fit.

Comment: Thank you very much!